# Previous year Year To Date with partial current year Year To Date Calculation SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a revenue table with data for last year and current year. I need to calculate the YTD last year and YTD current year, **BUT** I need to only consider data from min(date) from last year PER branch for current year YTD calculation.

eg: Branch KTM has data from 2018-02-25 not from Jan 1st. 
**Now I want to get YTD for the current year from the same date on 2019 till today.**

I am able to get whole YTD for last year and this year, and also the minimum date/weeknumber for each branch for last year, but unable to calculated partial YTD for the current year.

Here is one drive link to mydata and sql : https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ave_-9o8DQVEgRS7FaJmm48UNsWz?e=lRfOJF

[image]
A snippet from my code

I need help with the SQL query to do this.

Comment: Do you need the number of days between 2019-02-25 and today (2019-09-24)?

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result with your trials.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please do not use acronyms like YTD without explaining them, apart from computer and programming related and daily used acronyms you can't expect people to know what _your_ acronyms means.

Comment: Please show  sample data on your post.

Comment: @all Thanks for the inpuit, I have updated my question. In a simple sentence I would like to get the Year To Date revenue total for 2019 i.e. current year but considering only the data from min week to current week of 2018 data. I don't know how to explain my requirements more simpler, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the number of days between the same day-of-year of a last year's date and today's date:

```sql
select current_date - (date'2018-02-25' + interval '1' year); -- PostgreSQL
select datediff(current_date, (date'2018-02-25' + interval '1' year)); -- MySQL
```

Alternative version:

```sql
select extract(doy from current_date) - extract(doy from date'2018-02-25'); -- PostgreSQL
```

`doy` stands for *day of year*. At the time of the answer (2019-09-24) all queries return `211`.

To sum values in that date range, use `BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT sum(revenue) 
FROM your_table 
WHERE date BETWEEN date'2018-02-25' + interval '1' year AND current_date
```

Comment: I actually need to get the Year To Date sum of revenue not the dates. Please see my updated question

Comment: I need the minimum date for a branch last year dynamic sir,